# Show that if $I − AB$ is nonsingular, then $I − IK$ is nonsingular and: $(I−KC)^{−1} =I+B(I−LB)^{−1}C$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on my homework for my Linear Algebra course and I'm having trouble with this question. If anyone could help me I'd be grateful. Thanks!

$I − AB$ is nonsingular, then $I − IK$ is nonsingular and: $(I−KC)^{−1} =I+B(I−LB)^{−1}C$

Comment: You shouldn't edit your questions to hide what the actual question was. Regardless of whether the question is on hold or whatever, that just makes it harder for people to benefit from the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $I-CB$ is invertible, then

$\begin{align}I&= (I-CB)(I-CB)^{-1} \\&=(I-CB)^{-1} -CB(I-CB)^{-1}\end{align}$

$\Rightarrow (I-CB)^{-1}= I+CB(I-CB)^{-1}$

Now consider

$\begin{align}I+B(I-CB)^{-1}C&= I+B(I+CB(I-CB)^{-1})C\\&= I+BC+BCB(I-CB)^{-1}C \\&=I+BC(I+B(I-CB)^{-1}C) \end{align}$

$\Rightarrow (I-BC)(I+B(I-CB)^{-1}C)=I$ implying that $I-BC$ is invertible and $(I-BC)^{-1}= I+B(I-CB)^{-1}C$

Comment: thanks for the help. how did you arrive at that last implication?

Comment: $I+B(I-CB)^{-1}C = I +BC(I+B(I-CB))^{-1}C)$ so if $X= I+B(I-CB)^{-1}C$ then we have $X= I+BCX$ so that $X(I-BC)=I.$ I hope it's clear now

Comment: Do you mean $(I - BC)X = I$ ?

Comment: Sorry, that was what I meant. Thanks, I'll correct that.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Calculate
$$
(I-BC)(I+B(I-BC)^{-1}C)
$$
keeping in mind that 
$$(I-BC)B = B - BCB = B(I-CB)$$

**Edit:** Whole calculation:
$$
(I-BC)(I+B(I-BC)^{-1}C) = (I-BC)I + \color{red}{(I-BC)B}(I-CB)^{-1}C\\
= I-BC + \color{red}{B(I-CB)}(I-CB)^{-1}C\\
= I-BC + B\color{blue}{(I-CB)(I-CB)^{-1}}C\\
= I-BC + BC\\
= I
$$
where the red part is the hint from above, and the blue part is just one matrix multiplied with its inverse.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried a few things without success. Can you please guide me little further?

Comment: @PabloGuzman Added some detail.

Comment: Thank you this is very clear!